# virtualenv creation fails with error "StopIteration"

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-packaging

In attempt to slim down a Docker image with a large Python environment, I tried removing as many files and directories as possible (cached packages, `__pycache__` directories, `.pyc`, `.md`, `.txt` files, etc).

Now `pre-commit` initialization fails because it cannot create its virtual environment. I also cannot use `virtualenv` directly:

```bash
$ python -m virtualenv foo2
StopIteration:
```

Comment: Is there really not any more in the console output than that?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In CI/CD logs, I had a stack trace from `pre-commit` trying to create its virtual environment and this led me to [base.py#L120](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/main/src/virtualenv/seed/embed/via_app_data/pip_install/base.py#L120) where I discovered `entry_points.txt` being loaded. But in the console there is no more output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the removal of `entry_points.txt` from `site-packages/virtualenv-20.17.0.dist-info/`.

This files defines entry points, including `console_scripts` ones that allow the shell to call appropriate functions ([source](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/#file-format)).

Comment: The bottom line is: Do not meddle with `*.dist-info` directories.